# Swing java, make animation freeze

Tags: java, swing

I have made a simple swing java application. Everything it does, is displaying 3 buttons, and if user clicked on particular one, is starting an animation.

Here is code:

MyPanel.java

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    static final int DELAY = 111;
    int direction = 37;
    boolean running = false;
    Timer timer;
    int x = 400;
    int y = 300;

    MyPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 640));
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
        startGame();
    }

    public void startGame() {
        running = true;
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
    }

    public void move() {
        switch(direction){
            case 37:
                x -=10;
                break;
            case 38:
                y -=10;
                break;
            case 39:
                x +=10;
                break;
            case 40:
                y +=10;
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(running) {
            move();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case 37:
                    direction = 37;
                    break;
                case 38:
                    direction = 38;
                    break;
                case 39:
                    direction = 39;
                    break;
                case 40:
                    direction = 40;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + e.getKeyCode());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyFrame.java

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton start;
    JButton statistics;
    JButton quit;
    JPanel panel;

    public MyFrame() {
        this.setTitle("App");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        showMenu();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void showMenu(){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 640));
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 5;

        start = new JButton("Start");
        start.addActionListener(this);
        add(start, gbc);

        statistics = new JButton("Statistics");
        statistics.addActionListener(this);
        add(statistics, gbc);

        quit = new JButton("Quit");
        quit.addActionListener(this);
        add(quit, gbc);


        this.pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("Start")) {
            this.panel = new MyPanel();

            System.out.println("test");
            this.setVisible(false);
            add(panel);
            this.setContentPane(panel);
            this.setResizable(false);
            this.pack();
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
package com.company;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] main) {
        new MyFrame();

    }
}
```

First thing is I made those 3 buttons working at random and I don't know if it is programmed well. Second thing, I would like to add animation that displays counter from 3 to 1 after user clicked button "Start". I hope you understand me, if no, let me know.
Video that illustrates program:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OG3KSklcF0g&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=asdsad
Is there a way to make the counter without changing structure of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a countdown timer to your `MyFrame` class.

Here's the GUI before I left-click on Start.

[image: App 1]

Here's the GUI during the countdown.

[image: App 2]

I added a Swing `Timer` to your `MyFrame` `ActionListener`.

I started the Swing application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

You should use a `CardLayout` so you can get back to the main what should be the main `JPanel` with your buttons.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made your `MyFrame` and `MyPanel` classes inner classes so I could copy and paste one block of code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SimpleGame {

    public static void main(String[] main) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SimpleGame().new MyFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        JButton start;
        JButton statistics;
        JButton quit;
        JPanel panel;

        private JTextField countdownField;

        private Timer timer;

        public MyFrame() {
            this.setTitle("App");
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setResizable(false);
            showMenu();
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }

        public void showMenu() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 640));
            this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 3;

            JLabel countdownLabel = new JLabel("Countdown");
            countdownLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(countdownLabel, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            countdownField = new JTextField(4);
            countdownField.setEditable(false);
            countdownField.setFont(countdownField.getFont().deriveFont(48f));
            countdownField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
            add(countdownField, gbc);

            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            start = new JButton("Start");
            start.addActionListener(this);
            add(start, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            statistics = new JButton("Statistics");
            statistics.addActionListener(this);
            add(statistics, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            quit = new JButton("Quit");
            quit.addActionListener(this);
            add(quit, gbc);

            start.setPreferredSize(statistics.getPreferredSize());
            quit.setPreferredSize(statistics.getPreferredSize());

            this.pack();
        }

        public void updateCountdownField(int seconds) {
            countdownField.setText(Integer.toString(seconds));
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String command = e.getActionCommand();
            if (command.equals("Start")) {
                timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    int seconds = 3;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        updateCountdownField(seconds--);
                        if (seconds < -1) {
                            timer.stop();

                            MyFrame.this.panel = new MyPanel();

                            System.out.println("test");
                            MyFrame.this.setVisible(false);
                            MyFrame.this.add(panel);
                            MyFrame.this.setContentPane(panel);
                            MyFrame.this.setResizable(false);
                            MyFrame.this.pack();
                            MyFrame.this.setVisible(true);
                            MyFrame.this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
                timer.setInitialDelay(0);
                timer.start();
            }
        }

    }

    public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        static final int DELAY = 111;
        int direction = 37;
        boolean running = false;
        Timer timer;
        int x = 400;
        int y = 300;

        MyPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 640));
            this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            this.setFocusable(true);
            this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
            this.requestFocusInWindow();
            startGame();
        }

        public void startGame() {
            running = true;
            timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
            timer.start();
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            draw(g);
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
        }

        public void move() {
            switch (direction) {
            case 37:
                x -= 10;
                break;
            case 38:
                y -= 10;
                break;
            case 39:
                x += 10;
                break;
            case 40:
                y += 10;
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (running) {
                move();
                repaint();
            }
        }

        public class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case 37:
                    direction = 37;
                    break;
                case 38:
                    direction = 38;
                    break;
                case 39:
                    direction = 39;
                    break;
                case 40:
                    direction = 40;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException(
                            "Unexpected value: " + e.getKeyCode());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```